# The text of checkbox control in custom dialog can't be displayed in some android devices

Tags: android

I use the following code to create and open a custom dialog, it works well in android 4.2.2 , but the text of checkbox control can't be displayed in android 2.3.6.

I find the text of checkbox control is black,and the BackgroundColor of dialog is  white in android 4.2.2 , so it's OK, but and the BackgroundColor of dialog is  black in android 2.3.6, so it's bad.

How can I do?

**sms_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chNoDisplayAgain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"        
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Related java code:

```
 private void DisplayPrompt(final String key,final boolean isClose,String msg){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.sms_dialog, null);       
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.TitleWarning));      
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg); 
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

        final CheckBox myCheckBox=(CheckBox)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.chNoDisplayAgain);
        myCheckBox.setText(getString(R.string.NoDisplayAgain));     

        alertDialogBuilder
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.BtnOK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                   SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                   if (prefs.contains(key)){                     
                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor =prefs.edit();
                      editor.putBoolean(key, !myCheckBox.isChecked());
                      editor.commit();

                   }
                   if (isClose){
                      finish();
                   }
                }
            });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();  
        alertDialog.show();      
    }
```

Comment: Use scrollview instead of linear..

Comment: you can check if api version is 2.3.6 or below then set the color of checkbox something else something else?

Answer (score 2):

I use this line of code and it works fine. It will make dialog background same colour as you have on 11+ api

```
alertDialogBuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like santhosh suggested but  with a little twist.
I would:
create custom dialog style for new and old android version
put those xml files with styles to two folders: values and values-v11

The special folder name values-v11 has a so called qualifier that tells android to use this resource for honeycomb and above devices.
So, this way you can have one look for older and other look for newer devices with no changes to java code.
And if you are into this stuff, take a look at HoloEverywhere library.

Answer (score 1):

try this with textcolor and background color as below..

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertial"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="10dp" >
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chNoDisplayAgain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="" /></LinearLayout>

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.customDialogTheme));
```

> create style as u like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="customDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks! but it's not good. The background color is half white  and half black https://www.dropbox.com/s/em4x7zik2a4rltw/SC20131206-152213.png

Comment: u can also apply your theme...as
create a custom theme set background color as white and textcolor as black in style and supply this theme in
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,theme);

Comment: Thanks! Could you show some sample code about creating and applying theme to dialog?

Comment: Thanks! but your code have an error "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 '@android:style/AlertDialog'."

Comment: The ability to add a theme in the constructor was added with API 11, which is also when they added the Holo themes that the newer AlertDialogs use.

Comment: @user828896: I don't see any text which is "half black and half white", in your link. Do you mean "grey"?

Answer (score 0):

The only real solution for pre API 11 is to create the entire layout in XML.  You just need to add the TextView for the title, another one below it for the message, and the button.

Then the entire layout will use the default theme you have chosen for your app.  Or you can style it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your project add the folder

```
res/layout-v10
```

And create the file "sms_dialog.xml" with your code and the textColor defined :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chNoDisplayAgain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That way the color of the checkbox text will be white for android API 10 only (2.3.3 -
2.3.7). Android will use the layout file in "res/layout" the rest of the time.